# how to append variable value to th:href in thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

When I click a link (`brandname`) in front end, I need send a request to the server using `th:href` in thymeleaf. For that I followed below code

`<a th:href="@{*{category.url}}" th:text=*{brandname}></a>`

`category.url` and `brandname` values are coming dynamically from their respective `Objects`, But for above request I need to append extra content for that I tried something like below

`<a th:href="@{*{category.url}+'?someExtraContent'}" th:text=*{brandname}></a>`

and it is adding the extra content successfully, now my task is that 'extra content' I need to append dynamically, I read **Local Variable concept in thymeleaf** and I tried below code to append content to the request url dynamically

`<a th:with="var=*{brandname}" th:href="@{*{category.url}+'?'+var}"  th:text=*{brandname}></a>`

I assumed that the `var` will stores the value and it will append to the request url but it is not happening I am getting the url like below

**Ex:**
`localhost:8080/mycompany/mens?var`

But I need something like below

**Ex:**
`localhost:8080/mycompany/mens?nike`

can anyone help me how to append dynamic content to the request url in thymeleaf

Answer (score 1):

I found solution,

**Previous code**

`<a th:with="var=*{brandname}" th:href="@{*{category.url}+'?'+var}"  th:text=*{brandname}></a>`

I replaced above code with

`<a th:with="var=*{brandname}" th:href="@{*{category.url}+'?'+${var}}"  th:text=*{brandname}></a>`

Now I am able to append the dynamic content to my request url...

I have changed this `var` to `${var}`